# How do I execute an embedded file from a metro application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How do I execute an embedded file (.cmd) from my metro application? Does `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()` helps?

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded file"? Do you mean something in your .appx package?

Comment: You is not in general possible from a Store app.  Hiding executables as resources is completely off the table, that never passes store verification.

Answer (score 2):

From [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/14e2be68-ef86-4480-a3fd-6ddf7ec7d1f1) I'm going to say that isn't possible.  Windows store apps have a very restricted sandbox and calling other executables would fall outside of what is allowed.